# Reference request: $ \psi(x) - \frac{1}{2} \| \nabla \psi(x) \|^2 = c(x) $

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, geometric-analysis

I have a Riemannian manifold $M$ of dimension 2 on which I am considering the following equation:

$$ \psi(x) - \frac{1}{2} \| \nabla \psi(x) \|^2 = c(x) $$

on some patch $U$ of the manifold which is "stratified" into curves such that $c$ is constant on each such curve.

A $\psi$ and  $c$ that would satisfy the identity above would be $ \psi(x) = \frac{1}{2} \text{dist}(x, P)^2 $ and $ c \equiv 0 $, where $P \in M$, since $\nabla \psi(x) = - \exp^{-1}_x(P) $ and so $ \| \nabla \psi(x) \| = \text{dist}(x, P)$.

I am interested in whether this equation has any other solutions. I am sure this is something that has been studied, but I am not familiar with the area, so any reference would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I am slightly confused, if you take any smooth function $f$ then (if $c'(x_0)\neq 0$) in the vicinity of $x_0$ the level sets of $c$ will be "stratified" by the implicit function theorem, no?

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks!